# Vue infinite scroll with firebase is not working?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I've been trying a bunch of different ways and I haven't been having any success getting an infinite scroll to work, I've tried export default and then the setup() way as well but then I had to put it with setup in the script tag because I kept getting an error about too many exports.

Here's what I have on a composable page so that I can use it in multiple places without having to write it out all the time.

```js
import { projectFirestore } from "../Firebase/Config";
import { ref } from "vue"

const getPremium = () => {
    const Premium = ref([])
    const error = ref(null)

    const load = async () => {
        try{
            const res = await projectFirestore.collection('Premium').limit(8).get()
            if (lastPost) {
                res = res.startAfter(lastPost.createdAt)
              }
            
              const snapshot = await res.get()
            Premium.value = snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
               console.log(doc.data())
               return {...doc.data(), id: doc.id}
            })
        }
        catch (err){
            error.value = err.message
            console.log(error.value)
        }
    }

    return { Premium, error, load}
}

export default getPremium
```

Here's the script I have from vue.

```js
import { ref, reactive } from 'vue'
import getPremium from "../Composables/getPremium.js";
const {Premium, error, load} = getPremium();
load();
const state = reactive({
      posts: [],
      lastPost: null,
      fetching: false
    })

    const container = ref(null)

    const handleScroll = async () => {
      if (container.value.scrollTop + container.value.clientHeight >= container.value.scrollHeight && !state.fetching) {
        state.fetching = true

        const posts = await load(state.lastPost)
        state.posts = [...state.posts, ...posts]

        if (posts.length) {
          state.lastPost = posts[posts.length - 1]
        }

        state.fetching = false
      }
    }
```

Here is what the template is

```js
<div @scroll="handleScroll"

 <div v-for =" Premiums in Premium" :key="Premiums.id" >
 <router-link :to="{ name: 'Samplepremium', params: { id: Premiums.id }</router-link>
</div>
```

That's what I have got after trying it the latest way but I keep getting an errors no matter what I try at the moment it's `lastPost` is not defined.
I've been struggling with this for a while now so any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.